# HTML Help for Tumblr Blog

Tags: html, tumblr

there’s something wrong with the ‘home’ button on my tumblr blog.

it works when I’m on other pages on my blog (ex. about, message) but it doesn't work when i’m already on the home page.

when click 'home' on other blogs, it refreshes the page for me. it doesn't work when i do that on my blog.

the code for my home button is `<a href="/">Home</a>`

i don’t want to add a ‘back to top’ button because they mess up my blog :(

is there anything i can add to the code to make it work?

[here's a link to my blog](http://waffle-wink.tumblr.com)

```
<a href="#">Home</a>
```

that won't work either

Comment: testing on your blog, when I click 'home' that s refresh home page. Then what do you want to do exactly ?

Comment: You [already asked this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410569/home-button-on-blog-not-working/18424576#18424576).

Answer (score 1):

You already asked this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18410569/home-button-on-blog-not-working/18411195#18411195

But basically you shouldn't have a forward slash there. Instead, try index.php or whatever your home page is named.

Comment: index.php and my home page name won't work :(

Comment: Could you send me a link to your blog please, I'll check it out.

Comment: http://waffle-wink.tumblr.com/

Comment: change href="/" to href="http://waffle-wink.tumblr.com" or use href="javascript:history.go(0)"